# MYSQL Seeking mysqld startup option guidance

Tags: mysql

My apologies, if this is a rudimentary question, but I have been searching for answer via this site and others.  I have a MySQL (5.6.13) database which  was patched over the weekend. However, there was no documentation on the startup procedures.  I was able to get it restarted eventually, but now I'm encountering a couple of issues, which I believe are addressed in the startup options, but not finding anything on it. This system has been running for 4+ years, with only minor issues. Today as I repopulating data via the scripts, I've hit two issues.

**Issue 1:** Mysql Error: 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'ftsub' at row 1
This error is caused by this value: log_history_tam_dest. The column is a varchar size of 16.
Prior to the reboot, this value was truncated by MySQL, to log_history_tam_
Is there an option that will trim strings to fit in a column. I looked and haven't found it.

**Issue 2:** Mysql Error: 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'fid' at row 1.
This is defined as INT size 64. The value is 2216112200, which is larger than a signed int.  However, this was working with larger values. The current largest is: 3716111600.
Is there a startup option for my.cnf which will address these two issues?

*I understand the best is to fix the code, however, this is a legacy system which is being replaced. The client needs this running through the end of the year.*

Thank you,
Allan

Comment: Show the output from `SELECT @@SQL_MODE;` please.

Comment: "@@SQL_MODE"
"STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` is the issue, here.  It's enabled by default in the config file, starting in 5.6.  With this enabled:

> For transactional tables, an error occurs for invalid or missing values in a data-change statement when either `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` or `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` is enabled. The statement is aborted and rolled back.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Find `sql-mode` in the config file and remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and restart the server.

Comment: Thank you.  That corrected the initial issue. Now I must clean up from the results of the setting being in place.